# 型の不一致　kotlin.IntArray

Tags: java, kotlin

```
 public interface AsyncCallback {
     public fun preExecute()
     public fun postExecute(result: JSONObject)
     public fun progressUpdate(progress: Int)
     public fun cancel()
 }
```

〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜

```
fun onProgressUpdate(vararg _progress: Int) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*_progress)
        mAsyncCallback!!.progressUpdate(_progress[0])
    }
```

> *_progress

の部分でエラーが出ています

> Type mismatch Required: kotlin.Array<(out) kotlin.Int!>! Found:
>   kotlin.IntArray

Javaの場合Integerですが、Kotlinだとエラーになります。

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... _progress)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
↓値の渡し先

```
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
}
```

直し方がわかりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

勝手な推測ですがおそらく`android.os.AsyncTask`の`onProgressUpdate`メソッドをオーバライドしたいんですね。
であれば`override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg p: Int?)`というシグネチャにすれば解決するはずです。
下記コードはvalidです(Kotlinのバージョンは1.0.0-beta-1103)。

```
class Foo: AsyncTask<A, Int, C>() {
    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg p: Int?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*p)
    }
}
```

質問内容とは関係ないアドバイスですが、質問内容をもう少し具体的かつシンプルにすると回答が集まりやすいと思いますよ。例えば使用しているKotlinバージョンなど。
あとはまずKotlinのドキュメントを一通り読んでみてはいかがでしょうか？